# Login authentication with Ember-cli, Rails and ember-cli-simple-auth-token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I have created an ember-cli project (v 0.1.12) with ember.js (v 1.8.1) and Rails. Than I tried to install:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-simple-auth-token

but when I run the login POST the server responds to me with this error:

> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

I notice that it sends only username and password, without token. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can fix that issue in the development setting by disabling CSRF tokens all together. You wouldn't use that in production but you can at least disable it to confirm that the issue gets fixed. In the application_controller.rb file, remove: protect_from_forgery line. Also go to your session_store.rb file in initializers and set:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Rails.application.config.session_store :disabled
```

Once you get things working, you can re-add the protect_from_forgery line as so:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```